# Help with asp.net mvc and jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

```
$("#add_activity").click(function () {
            $('#activities').append('@Html.Raw(Html.Partial("MyPartial").ToHtmlString())');
        });
```

I have this bit of code that seems to be working just fine if the partial is this:

```
<tr><td>Foo</td><td><input type="text" name="bar" /></td></tr>
```

But fails to work if the partial is this

```
<tr>
     <td>
         Foo
     </td>
     <td>
        <input type="text" name="bar" />
     </td>
</tr>
```

How can I get around this??.. Having it all in one line is terrible.

Please help.

Comment: NachoF - I've never seen this issue before - ever :0). would you be good enogh to post ALL relevant code, including the contoller code. it just doesn't add up..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's normal. If you view the source code of your generated page you will see this:

```
$('#activities').append('
<tr>
     <td>
         Foo
     </td>
     <td>
        <input type="text" name="bar" />
     </td>
</tr>
');
```

which obviously is very far from something that could be considered as valid javascript.

You could use the [JavaScriptStringEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.javascriptstringencode.aspx) method like this:

```
$("#add_activity").click(function () {
    $('#activities').append('@HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(Html.Partial("MyPartial").ToHtmlString())');
});
```

which will take care of properly encoding the HTML string and you will end up with valid javascript:

```
$("#add_activity").click(function () {
    $('#activities').append('\u003ctr\u003e\r\n     \u003ctd\u003e\r\n         Foo\r\n     \u003c/td\u003e\r\n     \u003ctd\u003e\r\n        \u003cinput type=\&quot;text\&quot; name=\&quot;bar\&quot; /\u003e\r\n     \u003c/td\u003e\r\n\u003c/tr\u003e');
});
```

which produces the desired result.

Comment: almost there.. but now its adding an extra " to the type and name attrbiutes.. so Im getting <input type=""text"" name=""bar"" />

Comment: @NachoF, yes indeed there's an additional double quote. Can you use AJAX instead? It would be more optimized because you won't be sending the partial to the client unless he clicks on the button.

Answer (score 0):

This works in MVC3:

```
@{
    Layout = null;
    var s = HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(Html.Partial("Banner").ToHtmlString().ToString());
}
<iframe id="banner" src="about:blank" frameborder="0"></iframe>
<script type="text/javascript">
     var doc = document.getElementById('banner').contentWindow.document;
     doc.open();
     doc.write("@Html.Raw(s)");
     doc.close();
</script>
```